# Which is grammatically correct, "I" personally, or "me" personally?

Tags: grammaticality

"Good luck to each of you with your endeavors, and if the Association, or me personally, can do anything to assist you, please don't hesitate to contact me."

Comment: Hi Dean, welcome to ELU! Could you tell us specifically what you're having trouble understanding?

Comment: Depends if it's the subject or predicate of the sentence in question.

Answer (score 1):

In your example sentence, "I" seems to be the correct choice. If we remove 'if the Association' for the sake of convenience, then we have 'Me personally can do anything to assist you'. It's pretty clear here that using "Me" in this context is erroneous.

However, the sentence still comes out just a wee bit clumsily.

Would it be possible for you to rephrase it as "Good luck to each of you with your endeavors, and if either the Association or myself can do anything to assist you, please don't hesitate to contact me"? You can consider other alternatives like "and if either I or the Association" or "and the Association or I".

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this with one being a run-on sentence. So, I've rearranged it to be grammatically correct. As you can see, "personally" can be placed in different places. I hope this helps. - Editor Su

Good luck to each of you with your endeavors. If the Association or I can assist you personally, please don't hesitate to contact me.

Or

Good luck to everyone with your future endeavors. If you need any assistance from me or the association, please don't hesitate to contact me personally.